# How to add a skybox to camera and using layer to show it only in main menu?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 3 scenes and I want that when the main menu scene is active to display a specific skybox.

This is what I did so far :

1. Added a new layer called it Skybox Planet
2. Disabled the player camera.
3. Changed the layer in the main menu camera to be Skybox Planet.
4. Changed in the main menu camera the Culling Mask to only Skybox Planet
5. In Window > Rendering > Lightning Settings > Skybox Material dragged to there my Skybox.

Screenshots :

1. The Main Menu Camera Inspector settings : You can see in the background in both scene view and game view the skybox and how bad it looks like :

[image: main menu camera settings and the skybox in the background looks bad and the background should not looks like that at all]

2. The Lightning Settings window after dragged the Skybox_0000 and the warning I'm getting there in yellow :

[image: Lightning Settings window]

The problems are also mentioned above are :

1. The skybox is looks very bad in both scene view and game view windows.
2. There is a warning in the Lightning Settings window in the Skybox Material field.

Last this is how the skybox should looks like in the sceneview and in the gameview if looking from inside the spaceship :

[image: This is how the skybox should look like]

Update on what I did last :

I changed the skybox material shader to Skybox/6 Sided and then added to each side a skybox texture :

but it seems wrong maybe I added the texture in the wrong order ? When I'm running the game using a script to rotate the skybox it looks like it's moving to the side and not that the camera moving around the skybox. The effect by rotating the skybox should also be looks like the camera is moving around the planet.

You can see on the left the scene view and game view windows how it looks like wrong.

[image: Material with shader and textures is wrong]

And this is the textures in the Assets :

[image: Skybox textures]

The effect should be like the skybox is 3d planet and the camera is rotating around it I'm rotating the skybox but this is the effect I want to get.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is just where you placed the 6 sides. You need to Swap these:

1. Front +Z is correct
2. Back -Z should be the Left +X
3. left +X should be Right -X
4. Right -X should be Back -Z
5. Up +Y is correct
6. Down -Y is correct